# Blank Windows Feature list when loading through C#

Tags: c#, windows, process

I want to be able to open the "Windows Features" menu in my C# application, but for some reason, it'll show a blank Windows Features list, but only on some machines. I've ran this on another Windows 7 VM and it worked perfectly fine, but when doing this on my machine (and my friends machine), it left us with a blank list.

Here's the code I use to open "Windows Features". If I run this with CMD manually it works files however - only in the C# application will it cause problems.

```
Process.Start("OptionalFeatures.exe");
```

The same problem will happen if I use this as well

```
Process.Start("control.exe", "appwiz.cpl,,2");
```

Any ideas on why this is happening..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying a platform target corresponding to your OS platform.

I assume the computers that run into this problem are 64 bit machines and your application runs in 32bit mode. So try specifying either platform target = AnyCpu AND disable the checkbox "prefer 32 bit" or set the platform target to 64bit.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find any boxes that would let me set that, but I found a workaround for it: http://www.quantcode.com/modules/smartfaq/faq.php?faqid=105
Thanks! It works just fine now!